# How to keep the Character Count Text View Blank when an Edit text is empty in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, textview

So I already figured out how to have the word count show during the user typing inside the EditText, but Now I want the character count to be blank when there is no characters in the text field.

Here's a pick of what I am talking about.

[image]

And here's the code that is connecting the word count to the Edit Text

```
itemView.date_time_add.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher{
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, end: Int) {
                    itemView.cCount1.text = ""
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, end: Int) {
                    if (s.isNullOrEmpty()){
                        itemView.cCount1.text = ""
                    }
                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    if (s != null) {
                        itemView.cCount1.text = "${225 - s.length} Characters Remaining"
                    }
                }

            } )
```

Any ideas is welcomed, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide or show the View you can use `.visibility` property. To show you can use `View.VISIBLE`, and to hide `View.GONE` or `View.INVISIBLE`

```
override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, end: Int) {
    if (s.isNullOrEmpty()){
        itemView.cCount1.visibility = View.GONE
    } else {
        itemView.cCount1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Reference for more details: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setVisibility(int)

Comment: Your absolutely correct, I didn't think about hiding the actual view itself. Thanks for the help.